# Java threadsafe single update

Tags: java, concurrency, atomicreference

I have a scenario where threads using single object and in case of a failure, update object once and other getters/threads uses the new updated object.

I am planning to use AtomicReference but not sure if updateAndGet makes sure of achieving this.

I am open to use guave etc too.

Can you provide an example for this ?

Comment: Do you want object to be updated exactly once - on the first failure?

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `volatile` reference?

Comment: @G.Domozhirov that’s correct. I would like to have it updated only once and keep using it as is until next failure.

Comment: That's the opposite of what he said.

Comment: @shmosel is this for me? Not sure if that’s opposite. Explain if so please.

Comment: @G.Domozhirov asked if you're updating it only on the first failure and the answer is, no, you're updating it on every failure.

Comment: After a failure happens, in order to use it one has to update the value. I believe your argument is more of philosophical. The aim is pretty clear I suppose.

Comment: Anyway, you could use both volatile and AtomicReference.

Comment: @shmosel, technically it wouldn't be updated if it didn't fail.  They're saying that they are checking the value before updating it.